# Creating Apache Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow[MWAA]: INCORRECT_CONFIGURATION

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, mwaa

I'm creating Apache airflow in console.

Status: Create failed

Last update: Error code: INCORRECT_CONFIGURATION

Message: You may need to check the execution role permissions policy for your environment, and that each of the VPC networking components required by the environment are configured to allow traffic. Troubleshooting: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html

I have read the network configurations, created two private subnet in my default VPC, created NAT gateway and added the NAT gateway route to Private subnet route table? What else am I missing?

Comment: Are you running a CloudFormation template? Where did you get the template? Please tell us more! For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm creating from console

Comment: Good place to start is this tool: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/MWAA It runs a number of diagnostic tests of your MWAA instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created 2nd NAT and added the route in second private subnet. Now I'm able to create the environment without any issues

Comment: this is not my case :/
I tried to create the environment with quick start guide, but after 4 hours throw incorrect_configuration

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I wish I could help. Hours and hours wasted here too. This may in fact be the ABSOLUTE WORST thing I've ever seen in AWS. Literally dozens of resources are prerequisite and while standing up MWAA it does a dry run check. Yet, the best error it gives you is INCORRECT_CONFIGURATION?!

There is an accompanying message which is the most vague thing ever--it essentially says "you may need to check EVERYTHING" with a link to a troubleshooting document I've been over like 30 times and I still cannot get it to work.

Just wow. fml.

Comment: you comment perhaps might not be considered as answer. please update it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Encountered the same issue - while the traceback said it was networking related (pasted below), the failure was caused by a conflict in the MWAA airflow version (2.5.1) and the version in our requirements.txt file still being the previous version:
apache-airflow==2.2.2
All that to say - the traceback is vague, but hopefully this gives you one more thing to check.
There's also and AWS support tool for verifying your MWAA environment: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/tree/master/MWAA

```
Status
FAILED
Created at
2023-07-06T18:48:44.000Z
Error code
INCORRECT_CONFIGURATION
Message
You may need to check the execution role permissions policy for your environment, and that each of the VPC networking components required by the environment are configured to allow traffic.
```

Answer (score -1):

When you will create mwaa environment create a new MWAA VPC by clicking on the right side and that will use cloudformation stack to setup all your vpc configuration to launc MWAA

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).